# Using third party template file on product detail page magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, product-detail-page

Hello,

I have installed FAQ module from github https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-faqs-extensions.

I want to show the faq/view.phtml template file on product details page over here https://prnt.sc/tgofxd.

I have added the questions in Frequently Asked questions, they are visible on https://e92rduand89atx1x.mojostratus.io/faqs.html page See https://prnt.sc/tgogge but not on Product detail page See https://prnt.sc/tgofxd

You can refer these url for reference :

1. https://e92rduand89atx1x.mojostratus.io/faqs.html
2. https://e92rduand89atx1x.mojostratus.io/zorb-fabric30.html

Can you please guide me on this?
Here is the phtml file code.

```
<div class="faq-category">
<h2 class="faqcat-title first-title"><i></i><?php echo __('Welcome to our support portal');?></h2>
<?php if ($this->getFaqCategoriesList()): ?>
    <ul class="category-list">
        <?php foreach ($this->getFaqCategoriesList() as $category): ?>
            <li class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 category">
                <div class="block">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getFaqCategoryFullPath($category['identifier']); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo !empty($category['image']) ? $this->getFileBaseUrl($category['image']) : $block->getViewFileUrl('PHPCuong_Faq::images/faq81x81.png'); ?>" alt="<?php echo __($category['title']);?>" title="<?php echo __($category['title']);?> - <?php echo __('FAQs'); ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getFaqCategoryFullPath($category['identifier']); ?>">
                            <?php echo __($category['title']);?>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <ol class="items faqs-list">
        <li class="item no-question">
            <a href="#"><?php echo __('There are no FAQ Categories was found.'); ?></a>
        </li>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>

<h2 class="faqcat-title">
    <i></i><?php echo __('Frequently Asked Questions');?>
</h2>
<?php if ($this->getFrequentlyAskedQuestion()): ?>
    <ol class="items faqs-list">
        <?php foreach($this->getFrequentlyAskedQuestion() as $faq): ?>
            <li class="item" id="faq-id-<?php echo $faq['faq_id']; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getFaqFullPath($faq['identifier']); ?>"><span class="faq-iconplus"></span><?php echo $faq['title']; ?></a>
                <div class="description" id="description">
                    <?php echo $block->filterProvider($faq['content']); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="read-more"><?php echo __('Read more'); ?></div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php else: ?>
    <ol class="items faqs-list">
        <li class="item no-question">
            <a href="#"><?php echo __('There are no frequently asked questions was found.'); ?></a>
        </li>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>

<h2 class="faqcat-title"><i></i><?php echo __('Latest Questions');?></h2>
<?php if ($this->getLastestFAQ()): ?>
    <ol class="items faqs-list">
        <?php foreach($this->getLastestFAQ() as $faq): ?>
            <li class="item" id="faq-id-<?php echo $faq['faq_id']; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getFaqFullPath($faq['identifier']); ?>"><span class="faq-iconplus"></span><?php echo $faq['title']; ?></a>
                <div class="description" id="description">
                    <?php echo $block->filterProvider($faq['content']); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="read-more"><?php echo __('Read more'); ?></div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
<?php else: ?>
    <ol class="items faqs-list">
        <li class="item no-question">
            <a href="#"><?php echo __('There are no latest questions was found.'); ?></a>
        </li>
    </ol>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the layout file code "catalog_product_view.xml" where i am calling this phtml file

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="faq.faq.view" template="PHPCuong_Faq::faq/view.phtml"  group="detailed_info" cacheable="false">
      <arguments>
         <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">FAQ</argument>
          <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">100</argument>
         </arguments>
         </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

What is going wrong? Please help

Comment: This problem is still not resolved. Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

**Try it like this :-**

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="faq.faq.view" template="Learning_Module::shipping.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                    <arguments>
                        <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">FAQ</argument>
                        <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">100</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </referenceBlock>
```

Hope This Helps!

Comment: No this did not work. It even removed the FAQ tab from product detail page

Comment: there was a mistake i had jsut updated the ans try it now

Comment: No. this also not working

Comment: can you please share that module link i will try it on my local and then i will repost an ans

Comment: here it is https://github.com/php-cuong/magento2-faqs-extensions.

Comment: Did you tried??